# Rails 7 - Accessing joined model generate new query

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I have Rails 7 project where I've got tables

**Pipelines**

```rb
class Pipeline < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states, inverse_of: :pipeline, dependent: :destroy  
end
```

**States**

```rb
class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pipeline, inverse_of: :states 
  has_many :items, inverse_of: :state
end
```

**Items**

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state, inverse_of: :items
end
```

I wrote a query to limit only specific items on state

```rb
@pipeline = Pipeline.joins(states: :items)
                    .where(states: { items: { name: "Lorem" } })
                    .find_by(id: '123')
```

query:

```rb
Pipeline Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "pipelines".* FROM "pipelines" INNER JOIN "states" ON "states"."pipeline_id" = "pipelines"."id" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."state_id" = "states"."id" WHERE "items"."name" = $1 AND "pipelines"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["name", "Lotem"], ["id", "123"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

but once I call states from pipeline it generates new query without limitation:

```rb
puts @pipeline.states.inspect

State Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."pipeline_id" = $1 /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT $2  [["pipeline_id", "123"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

I'm expecting that it should grab states from collection it already has loaded,
am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but once I call states from pipeline it generates new query without
> limitation

yeah, that's how [`joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) work, it doesn't do more than that so the docs even don't bother adding more information. If you want to access the states within a single query (really it'll end up being 2 queries) you could use `includes` instead;

[ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#includes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes);

> Specify relationships to be included in the result set. It allows you
> to access the address attribute of the User model without firing an
> additional query.

and your query would slightly change to;

```
Pipeline
  .includes(states: :items)
  .where(items: { name: "Lorem" })
  .find('123')
```

The fact that invoking `states` on a Pipeline instance makes a new query is because you're invoking an instance method on that object which by definition makes a new query. Active Record won't know that you're referring to something that was already created in the query unless is specified otherwise (by using a custom `select` clause or similar).

---

Notice

`Pipeline.joins(states: :items).where(items: { name: "Lorem" })` is the same as `Pipeline.joins(states: :items).where(states: { items: { name: "Lorem" } })`, you don't need to nest items under states.

Comment: Just for clarification `find_by` and `find` are not the same .. for existing record result is the same but in case when record cannot be found `find` method will throw an exception unlike `find_by` which will return nil